# GCC build. Expected error

Tags: c++, gcc

I am not an expert in any of the languages or GCC. So my question might be sub-par.

I am building a code base with thousands of CPP files using GCC. In a file say `A.cpp` I am calling some functions in `B.cpp` [`B.cpp` contains class method definitions for a class defined `B.h`]. The build was Ok. But then I excluded `B.o` from the makefile. So now object file `B.o` is not created. But in this case I was expecting an error at compilation or linking stage since `A.cpp` is referring functions from `B.cpp`. But there was none and the code still builds without errors.  But when I moved the fn calls from `A.cpp` to another file `C.cpp` it gave me a linker error which is what I believe, the expected behavior.

Is this the expected behaviour? Also I checked a map file created during build, which listed all the function names, and the functions from `B.cpp` was present in the map even though the object file for B.cpp was not created. So my question is why there was no errors when I called functions from a file that is not part of the build. I tried deleting all the object files and binaries from the previous builds to clean up any residues that may exist, but to no avail. I am having no clues. Can anyone offer some help?

In my map file, normal functions are listed like

`80010820 T __gccmain`

`80010828 t __gccmain_end` etc

But the fns from B.cpp is listed as

`U CNvThread::ProcMsgReq(unsigned, void*)`

`U CNvDbMgrThread::Singleton(unsigned long)`

Comment: "T" means the ("text", subroutine name) symbol is defined in the .o.  "U" means the symbol is "undefined" in the module (i.e. that function or variable is external, and must be resolved by the linker).  If there's no "T" in B.o that corresponds to a "U" in any other module ... then "B.o" isn't needed.  Here's a list of "T", "U" and the other symbols: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm

Comment: PS: I noticed you said below that "after you did a 'clean', B.o wasn't rebuilt".  That's probably another clue that "B.o" simply isn't needed for this build.  Perhaps B.cpp is for a different architecture or platform?  Either way - if you don't need it, then you certainly shouldn't worry about it :)  IHMO...

Comment: @paulsm4 : Thanks for the insights. Just to clarify, If a symbol is listed as U then can I expect a linker error when the corresponding object file is not there? `B.o` was not rebuilt because I purposefully commented the line to include `B.o` in the make file.

Answer (score 1):

If `B.o` was still there from the previous build, it will link against the old copy just fine (unless something major changed).  If you didn't build the final executable, and only `A.o`, then that's still no problem because `A.o` references the functions from `B`, but isn't linked up with them until the final output file link.

Again, if `B.o` was still there from the previous build, it will be used, which is why it showed up in the map file.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. `B.o` was there from the previous build. I will try deleting this.

Comment: Cleaning the output folder did not work :(. Added additional info in the question.

Comment: I don't understand. `B.o` is not dropping in from thin air. Either it's not used in your executable or something is off. Unfortunately you need to be able to see the whole project to understand how these things happen.

Comment: I verifed that `B.o` is not created during build. Also verified that the these calls to this fns are actually getting compiled. I know this is messy. I will sort this out and update. Thanks for your suggestions. It helped.

Comment: I got a clearer picture of things. Adding it as answer so that it may help others just in case

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a "makefile": good.

By default, "make" will (usually) try to build your project.  That's the standard convention, anyway.

Typically, make will also have other "targets".  For example, you could type "make clean" or "make cleanall".  If these targets existed, they would *delete* your binaries, so you could rebuild from scratch.

I suspect when you re-ran "make", it picked up the old binary from your last build.  Did you check if it exists?

Otherwise, I guess your project never actually needed it in the first place :)

Running "ld -M" to generate a map (which should include a cross-reference) is a good way to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. there exists a make clean. I will try this and update.

Comment: You said "it picked up the old binary from your last build." Just to clarify, by `Binary`, you meant `object file` or `final linked executable`?

Comment: Cleaning the output folder did not work :(. Added additional info in the question.

Comment: I got a clearer picture of things. Adding it as answer so that it may help others just in case

Answer (score 0):

The expected errors were ignored by the linker since the line that created `A.o` was not compiled in because of a `#if`.

`#if (OBJ_A_SUPPORTED)`

`A* a = new A();`

`#endif`

The header file in which OBJ_A_SUPPORTED define was moved.

This led the linker to exclude fns from A.cpp and in turn removed the call to fns in `B.cpp`. So there was no linker errors. A good look at the map file may yield some clues in such cases which I totally missed out.